# Subtract seconds from datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I have an int variable that are actually seconds (lets call that amount of seconds `X`). I need to get as result current date and time (in datetime format) minus `X` seconds.

### Example

If `X` is 65 and current date is `2014-06-03 15:45:00`, then I need to get the result `2014-06-03 15:43:45`.

### Environment

I'm doing this on Python 3.3.3 and I know I could probably use the `datetime` module but I haven't had any success so far.

Comment: You should look at the `timedelta` class in `datetime`.  It allows you to specify a length of time which can then be added to / subtracted from datetime objects.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Using the `datetime` module indeed:

```
import datetime

X = 65
result = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=X)
```

You should read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) of this package to learn how to use it!

Comment: That's wayyyy too much work, so thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Consider using [`dateutil.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html), instead of [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 3, 22, 55, 9, 680637)
>>> now - relativedelta(seconds=15)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 3, 22, 54, 54, 680637)
```

In this case of a 15 seconds delta there is no advantage over using a stdlib `timedelta`, but `relativedelta` supports larger units such as months or years, and it may handle the general case with more correctness (consider for example special handling required for leap years and periods with daylight-savings transitions).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @julienc's answer, 
(in case it is helpful to someone)

If you allow X to accept positive or negatives, and, change the subtraction statement to an addition statement, then you can have a more intuitive (so you don't have to add negatives to negatives to get positives) time adjusting feature like so:

```
def adjustTimeBySeconds(time, delta):
    return time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=delta)

time = datetime.datetime.now()
X = -65
print(adjustTimeBySeconds(time, X))
X = 65
print(adjustTimeBySeconds(time, X))
```