# How to remove seconds from datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have the following date and I tried the following code,

```
df['start_date_time'] = ["2016-05-19 08:25:00","2016-05-19 16:00:00","2016-05-20 07:45:00","2016-05-24 12:50:00","2016-05-25 23:00:00","2016-05-26 19:45:00"]
df['start_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime([df['start_date_time']).replace(second = 0)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'second'
```

Comment: You can try: `df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))`

Comment: Do you want `string` or `datetime` objects? If you just want strings, you could remove the trailing seconds with a regex `':\d\d$'`.

Comment: i would like to get it as a datetime object

Comment: Checkout this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025552/subtract-seconds-from-datetime-in-python

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773342/truncate-timestamp-column-to-hour-precision-in-pandas-dataframe/28783971#28783971

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Solutions if need **datetimes** in output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date_time': ["2016-05-19 08:25:23","2016-05-19 16:00:45"]})
df['start_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date_time'])
print (df)
       start_date_time
0  2016-05-19 08:25:23
1  2016-05-19 16:00:45
```

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by minutes `T` or `Min`:

```
df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'].dt.floor('T')

df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'].dt.floor('Min')
```

---

You can use convert to `numpy values` first and then truncate `seconds` by cast to `<M8[m]`, but this solution remove possible timezones:

```
df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'].values.astype('<M8[m]')
print (df)
      start_date_time
0 2016-05-19 08:25:00
1 2016-05-19 16:00:00
```

Another solution is create `timedelta` Series from [`second`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.second.html) and substract:

```
print (pd.to_timedelta(df['start_date_time'].dt.second, unit='s'))
0   00:00:23
1   00:00:45
Name: start_date_time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'] - 
                        pd.to_timedelta(df['start_date_time'].dt.second, unit='s')
print (df)
      start_date_time
0 2016-05-19 08:25:00
1 2016-05-19 16:00:00
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date_time': ["2016-05-19 08:25:23","2016-05-19 16:00:45"]})
df['start_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date_time'])

#20000 rows
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)


In [28]: %timeit df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['start_date_time'].dt.second, unit='s')
4.05 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [29]: %timeit df['start_date_time1'] = df['start_date_time'].values.astype('<M8[m]')
1.73 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [30]: %timeit df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'].dt.floor('T')
1.07 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit df['start_date_time2'] = df['start_date_time'].apply(lambda t: t.replace(second=0))
183 ms ± 19.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

Solutions if need **strings** repr of datetimes in output

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print(df['start_date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
0    2016-05-19 08:25
1    2016-05-19 16:00
Name: start_date_time, dtype: object
```

And if necessary set `:00` to seconds:

```
print(df['start_date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00'))
0    2016-05-19 08:25:00
1    2016-05-19 16:00:00
Name: start_date_time, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 15):

## Set seconds to 0

`pd.to_datetime` will return `datetime` objects, which have `second` as attribute : there's not much you can do about it. You can set `second` to `0`, but the attribute will still be here and the standard representation will still include a trailing `':00'`.

You need to apply `replace` on each element of `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date_time': ["2016-05-19 08:25:23","2016-05-19 16:00:45","2016-05-20 07:45:00","2016-05-24 12:50:00","2016-05-25 23:00:00","2016-05-26 19:45:00"]})
df['start_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date_time'])
df['start_date_time'] = df['start_date_time'].apply(lambda t: t.replace(second=0))

print(df)
#       start_date_time
# 0 2016-05-19 08:25:00
# 1 2016-05-19 16:00:00
# 2 2016-05-20 07:45:00
# 3 2016-05-24 12:50:00
# 4 2016-05-25 23:00:00
# 5 2016-05-26 19:45:00
```

`:23` and `:45` from the first times have been replaced by `:00`, but they are still printed.

## Remove `':00'` from the strings

If you just want a string representation of those times and only parse the strings to `datetime` objects in order to remove `':00'` at the end of the string, you could just remove the last 3 characters :

```
>>> "2016-05-19 08:25:00"[:-3]
'2016-05-19 08:25'
```

You could apply this to every element in your list, before initializing `df['start_date_time']`:

```
>>> start_date_time = ["2016-05-19 08:25:00","2016-05-19 16:00:00","2016-05-20 07:45:00","2016-05-24 12:50:00","2016-05-25 23:00:00","2016-05-26 19:45:00"]
>>> map(lambda s: s[:-3], start_date_time)
['2016-05-19 08:25', '2016-05-19 16:00', '2016-05-20 07:45', '2016-05-24 12:50', '2016-05-25 23:00', '2016-05-26 19:45']
```

## Display datetimes without seconds

If you want to work with `datetime` objects but don't want to show seconds :

```
print(df['start_date_time'].apply(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')))
# 0    2016-05-19 08:25
# 1    2016-05-19 16:00
# 2    2016-05-20 07:45
# 3    2016-05-24 12:50
# 4    2016-05-25 23:00
# 5    2016-05-26 19:45
# Name: start_date_time, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot with:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

As written in one of the comments, the above apply to the case where the dates are not strings. If they, however, are strings, you can simply slice the last three characters from each list in the list:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2016-05-19 08:25:00"]})

print(df['date'].map(lambda t: t[:-3]))
```

The above will output:

> ```
> 0    2016-05-19 08:25
> Name: date, dtype: object
> ```

Comment: The original data are strings, so I don't think t.strftime will work, will it?

Comment: You're right ! I misread the question ;P Added the case where the dates are strings

Comment: Note that your update wasn't written in the comments but in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

HTML Code:

```
< input type="time" class="form-control" name="meeting_time" required />
```

Python Django Code:

```
meeting_time = request.POST['meeting_time'] #Like your_time = "12:35:00"
get_time = meeting_time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Result is:

```
get_time = "12:35"
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert String to datetime object first, then you can use the replace method.

```
from _datetime import *


df = dict()
df['start_date_time'] = ["2016-05-19 08:25:00",
                         "2016-05-19 16:00:00",
                         "2016-05-20 07:45:00",
                         "2016-05-24 12:50:00",
                         "2016-05-25 23:00:00",
                         "2016-05-26 19:45:00"]

for dt in df['start_date_time']:
    cur_dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    cur_dt = cur_dt.replace(second=0)
    print(cur_dt)

    cur_dt_without_second = cur_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    print(cur_dt_without_second)

-------------------
2016-05-19 08:25:00
2016-05-19 08:25
2016-05-19 16:00:00
2016-05-19 16:00
2016-05-20 07:45:00
2016-05-20 07:45
2016-05-24 12:50:00
2016-05-24 12:50
2016-05-25 23:00:00
2016-05-25 23:00
2016-05-26 19:45:00
2016-05-26 19:45
```

Answer (score 1):

this is with the time module not datetime module but might be what your looking for...

```
import time
X = time.strftime("%H:%M")
print(X)
```

or you with seconds

```
import time
X = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(X)
```

Comment: Not downvoted, but: this is a big step towards answering the question, since it will, if the user knows what he/she is doing, take the last step to the correct answer. But notice it is not a direct answer to the question, since there is no resemblance between the type of input data you are using and what the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the seconds using a timedelta:

```
import datetime    
d = datetime.datetime.now() #datetime including seconds
without_seconds = d - datetime.timedelta(seconds=d.second)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to a datetime object and then manipulate that

```
>>> x = ["2016-05-19 08:25:00","2016-05-19 16:00:00","2016-05-20 07:45:00","2016-05-24 12:50:00","2016-05-25 23:00:00","2016-05-26 19:45:00"]
>>> for i in x:
...  y = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
...  z = datetime.datetime.strftime(y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
...  print (y, type(y))
...  print (z, type(z))
... 
(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 19, 8, 25), <type 'datetime.datetime'>)
('2016-05-19 08:25', <type 'str'>)
(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 19, 16, 0), <type 'datetime.datetime'>)
('2016-05-19 16:00', <type 'str'>)
(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 20, 7, 45), <type 'datetime.datetime'>)
('2016-05-20 07:45', <type 'str'>)
(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 24, 12, 50), <type 'datetime.datetime'>)
('2016-05-24 12:50', <type 'str'>)
(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 25, 23, 0), <type 'datetime.datetime'>)
('2016-05-25 23:00', <type 'str'>)
(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 26, 19, 45), <type 'datetime.datetime'>)
('2016-05-26 19:45', <type 'str'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned removed so I assumed you don't want the seconds or microsecond in the result.If this is the case then following might help:

`datetime_variable.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'")`

If you have datetime in string then you can convert it in datetime obj:

> > `from dateutil import parser`
> >
> > `datetime_variable = parser.parse(str_datetime_var)`
> >
> > `datetime_variable.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to remove seconds from datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime 
print(str(datetime.today())[:16])
```

Output:

```
2021-02-14 21:30
```

It effectively transforms the timestamp into text and leaves only the first 16 symbols.
Just don't lose yourself in all those brackets ;)