# How to remove seconds from timedelta variable?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to remove the seconds and microseconds from the timedelta variable using python. I have the following dataframe and i would like to remove the seconds.

```
df['Duration'] = ['03:12:37.771200','06:52:24.764500','13:19:57.325200','15:01:07.000200','04:05:06.722200','01:10:07.456200']
```

Comment: you have asked this question before...

Comment: Do you think datetime or timedelta?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove seconds from datetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387467/how-to-remove-seconds-from-datetime)

Comment: @jezrael i have edited it. thanks

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Yes, but another userl wanted to propose a different solution. And that was datetime variables and this is timedelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need trim seconds from timedelta convert to `numpy array` and then to `timedelta64[m]`:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].values.astype("timedelta64[m]")
```

---

```
dur = ['03:12:37.771200','06:52:24.764500','13:19:57.325200',
       '15:01:07.000200','04:05:06.722200','01:10:07.456200']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration':dur})

df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']).values.astype("timedelta64[m]")
print (df)
   Duration
0  03:12:00
1  06:52:00
2  13:19:00
3  15:01:00
4  04:05:00
5  01:10:00
```

Comment: This is another thing I must commit to memory.  This truncates the information, how would you round to the nearest minute if needed?

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is 2 different things - trim and round. For round is your solution, for trim my one.

Comment: `pandas` has a `floor` and `round`... I'm just wondering what the `numpy` equivalent would be for `round`

Comment: In my opinion no, it is similar as [`.values.astype('<M8[m]'`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43388413/2901002) for datetimes.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [**`round`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) method with `'T'` for minute

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']).round('T')

print(df)

   Duration
0  03:13:00
1  06:52:00
2  13:20:00
3  15:01:00
4  04:05:00
5  01:10:00
```

You can also use [**`floor`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']).floor('T')

print(df)

   Duration
0  03:12:00
1  06:52:00
2  13:19:00
3  15:01:00
4  04:05:00
5  01:10:00
```