# Trying to remove seconds from a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here is my code to remove the seconds that some values in my df['time'] column that have seconds (ie. 10:05:35).

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce').notna()]
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').notna()]
# Remove the seconds by setting the floor to minutes 'T'
df['time'] = df['time'].df.floor('T')
```

After running the above code I get this error, can anyone help?

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'df'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unfortunately can't comment yet, otherwise I would've commented.

Looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387467/how-to-remove-seconds-from-datetime) it seems you have made a typo and need `df['time'] = df['time'].dt.floor('T')` where the difference is the **dt** instead of the **df** in between the dots.